# How to get git-tfs to only checkin a range of changes to TFS (ie, not squash all commits into one)

Tags: version-control, tfs, git-tfs

I've been using git-tfs for a couple weeks now and really enjoying it. I came across a problem earlier today though. I had two commits into git which weren't related(though for question's sake, lets say they touched the same files). I went to check these changes into TFS and the only option I appear to have is to squash the two unrelated commits into one checkin.

How would I only checkin one commit to TFS at a time instead of it being squashed into a single commit?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git-Tfs: A TFS changeset per Git Commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333835/git-tfs-a-tfs-changeset-per-git-commit)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the command rcheckin (https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/wiki/Rcheckin).

`git tfs rcheckin`

It will check in all new commits (since tfs/default) on the current branch as separate changesets in tfs.