# Storing git commit metadata in TFS when using git-tfs

Tags: git, version-control, tfs, git-tfs

### Context

We're a team of developers collaborating using github. We need to mirror our release branch on TFS such that we have a tfs changeset for every git commit. It seems the best way to do this is using [git-tfs rcheckin](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/wiki/Rcheckin).

In a comment to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15013174/1591992) to [my previous git-tfs question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005647/one-to-one-mapping-of-git-commits-to-tfs-changesets-using-git-tfs-rcheckin), [Matt Burke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29691/matt-burke) told me that

```
All changesets will be attributed to you... git-tfs connects to TFS with your 
credentials, and there's not an "attribute this to someone else" parameter on 
checkin (at least, not that I know of).
```

### Correct commit -> changeset attribution

What ways do I have to identify the original commiter of such a tfs changeset attributed to me, if one is using only our tfs mirror?

Is there a way to store metadata in TFS, or is there a way to script git-tfs so that it adds this information to the commit message?

Comment: The best way is to loose TFS... or loose `git`. Trying to force either to do things the way the other works is just terminal masochism. Yes, you can use `git` to work locally and prepare stuff for TFS, but until there is some clean interaction set of packages, better hide it.

Comment: There is a big added value to use git-tfs when you are obliged to work with TFS as a main repository. Perhaps, git-tfs don't manage all the workflow but there is a lot of advantages over TFS if you work with the normal workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fix now in the trunk ( https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/pull/336 ) that has been released in the stable version.

You will have to configure and use an author file that match the windows users login to there email address. This file is used to commit in the name of the original commiter.

But there is a right that must be given in tfs permissions to be able to check-in on behalf of someone else.